# Copy Multiple Columns over by Column name

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy Columns over to another worksheet going by Column Name. The problem with the below code is that it copies over only the Price Calculator Status Column. It is overwriting the other two. Is there a better way to have this code modified so it appends rather than overwrite?

Dim aCell1, aCell2, aCell3 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String

```
strSearch1 = "Change Request Description"
strSearch2 = "Current State"
strSearch3 = "Price Calculator Status"

'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With wrkbk
    Set aCell1 = Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

   'Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell.Column).Copy

    Set aCell2 = Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch2, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell.Column).Copy

    Set aCell3 = Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch3, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
       ' MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & aCell.Address & vbCrLf & _
       ' "and the column number is " & aCell.Column

        '~~> Do the copying here
        Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell1.Column).Copy
        Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell2.Column).Copy
        Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell3.Column).Copy
    'Else
        'MsgBox "Search value not found"
    'End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi all, any update here about this?

Comment: you copy the columns in the above code, but you don't paste it anywhere....is what you after a simultaneous selection of multiple columns that you can then paste, and they'll be next to each other?

Comment: Yes. I want to copy the above three columns from the source worksheet which are not next to each other to a new worksheet so they are next to each other. Forgot to add the below piece of code for the paste sorry for that:    wrkbk.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Answer (score 0):

Change your copy lines to:

```
Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Range(Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell1.Column).Address & "," & Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell2.Column).Address & "," & Sheets("3. PMO Internal View").Columns(aCell3.Column).Address).Copy
```

This selects your columns in one step, as multiple areas like range("A:A, C:C, E:E"). the comma's are text string additions, as if you use a comma in the range command it has a different meaning.

Comment: Ok but when I paste, the ActiveSheet.Paste does not seem to paste correctly anymore for some of the columns. I get #REF! for some of the columns. How can i get it to paste by values so i dont have this issue.

Comment: Check by selecting the top cell in the column, so before activesheet.paste, do a activesheet.range("A1").select

Comment: whoops, misread that- use pastespecial values: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Not working. I lose all the formatting and colour and the values still show as !ref

Comment: Now, I'm also stumped. You should be able to use the variants of pastespecial to paste the formats (after pasting the values, just one more line similar to the values line), but #ref errors shouldn't occur on paste special vlaues - assuming they're not in your original values. If you have any changes to your sheet, or enter formulas in your macro, you might need to recalculate the sheet before pasting.